# EKS service cannot be accessed from internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-security-group, nlb

I have a service up and running in an EKS pod. This service can be accessed using the pod URL and it works fine. But when I hit the URL from the internet it complained that " site can't be reached". I have used a network Load Balancer and the target is the EC2 instances running on the pod.

The security group of the Ec2 instances is modified to allow All traffic/All/All/0.0.0.0/0 for both inbound and outbound rules.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the EKS service itself allowing ingress from 0.0.0.0/0? You can check that on the container level, pod level, node level(covered by the SG), and ofcourse ingress controller. Also do you allow intercluster comms? You can do this by adding a rule on EKS SG allowing all connections with source the EKS SG itself.

Comment: I access the service using the cluster IP address. but it doesn't let me access it from internet. Should I add a new rule to the SGs to the instances in EKS? If so what rule should I add?

Comment: In the clusters SG in EKS are you allowing ALL from the SG itself? Could you set up a bastion host in the same vpc and try to connect to your cluster? Usually you add a seperate SG for your EC2 nodes and it is there where you explicitly allow outside comms.

Comment: I used the SGs for the EC2s to allow outside communication, but no luck. it still shows This site cant be reached.

Answer (score 0):

**ClusterIP** should be used only for internal communication such as between your frontend and backend.

For external access (Internet), you should have deployed your **Service** type as **NodePort** (later use it with **Ingress**) or **LoadBalancer** type to expose your service.

- For **LoadBalancer** type, it will create a **Classic Load Balancer** on AWS.
- For **NodePort** with **Ingress**, it depends on your Ingress Controller that you deploy, such as [**AWS Load Balancer Controller**](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/) or [**NGINX Ingress Controller**](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/